# Making links active in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have some problems with Javascript. In fact, I'm just newbie in that script language so I need some help..
Q: how to make this link active:

```
<a href="#box1">something</a>
```

this link is just link to the div which is located in index.html file, so there is no loading of page. 
and here is the div

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
<h3><a name="box1">something</a></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `making active`

Comment: For example to change link's background color in order to show user where is he/she located.. in css there is this snap of code a:active {background:#fff;} but it doesnt work because there is no loading of page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just starting out, I'd suggest you use a library such as jQuery. So, if your HTML is like this:

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
<h3><a name="box1">something</a></h3>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">
<h3><a name="box2">something</a></h3>
</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">
<h3><a name="box3">something</a></h3>
</div>
```

And you have a CSS class called `youarehere`:

```
.youarehere { color:white; background:green; }
```

With jQuery you could write something along the lines of:

```
$(".box > a").click(function() {             // when clicking any of these links
    $(".box > a").removeClass("youarehere"); // remove highlight from all links
    $(this).addClass("youarehere");          // add highlight to clicked link
})
```

In plain JS, it takes a bit more effort to achieve this. Do yourself a favor and don't reinvent the wheel - people have already taken care of this, so use the product of their labor to make your life easier.

Comment: Why does each `div` need an id?

Comment: @user1807271 No reason.

Answer (score 0):

a:active means when you click the link the css properties will apply on the link, instead of using a:active use

```
a.visited{color:red;}
```

Comment: There is no use in css, it doesnt work, because page is not reloading when link is clicked, I need Javascript

Comment: $("a").click(function() {
    $(this).css('color','#FF0000');}) It's a global function, it will change the color of all the occurrences of 'a' tag.

Answer (score 0):

To change the link text color on mouse over use the following css:

```
<style type="text/css">
        a:hover{color:Red;}
    </style>
```