# Underlining link upon click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, underline

Okay, so I'm totally new to everything website-related, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that when a link is clicked in my header navbar, the link will be underlined.

[Here's my HTML](http://www.bootply.com/u8D4jb2XfV), including the CSS for the active link.

Now, for the javascript - to make the link active - what file do I use (I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 btw)? Do I use bootstrap.js, or do I create my own - like I did for my CSS.

If you could walk me through it, that would be great. Thanks.

*edit*:

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="custom-wrapper"> 
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>

                        <li class="dropdown">   
                            <a href="#3" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>3</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#3.1">3.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#3.2">3.2</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                        </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->
                        <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>

                    </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" --></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff; /* text color for active */
  background-color: #ff0000; 
  /*text-decoration: underline;*/
}
```

Comment: Include the code in the question itself. A link is *not* enough.

Comment: lol @ the question getting put on hold after it was answered. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few questions here so I'm going to break it down into smaller parts.

1. "to make the link active - what file do I use (I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 btw)?" - you're going to want to make your own file. You usually don't want to modify original framework files, it's much cleaner and easier to create your own files. Make a file called script.js and just import it in your html sheet.
2. How to make links 'active' - I'd rather not just give you a bunch of code but what might be easiest to do is to have a class called 'active' that you style in css, for example:

   `.active { color: red; text-decoration: underline; }`

and using jQuery you can do something like

```
$(".nav > a").click(function() {        
    $(".nav > a").removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active");          
})
```

to use jQuery you're going to import it in your head like any other js or css file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Used [this SO question as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098462/making-links-active-in-javascript).

Comment: Cool. I got it to work, but whenever I hover over the underlined link. The underline disappears. Is it because of my CSS: .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}? What should I state within the function so that when underlined, the link doesn't change color upon hover? Thanks.

Comment: that's exactly why, just add text-decoration: underline right after color:#fff and it should work

Comment: If that doesn't work - you might need to edit your original post and show us how you're importing your CSS files and bootstrap files in the head of your HTML doc

Comment: One last question though. Using your suggestion above of adding text-decoration: underline; to my code from my CSS - that causes there to be an underline on those links that aren't even active when hovered over. Is there a way to modify the function so that the link must be active in order for that to happen?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your classes but essentially you're going to want to nest that underline decoration in the active tag, so something like nav active:hover { text-decoration: underline }

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the javascript code:

```
$(function() {

    $(".navbar-nav li a").on('click', function() {
        $(".navbar-nav li a").css('text-decoration', 'none');
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    });

});
```

So that when you click an item, it will be underlined

Comment: Using your code, how would I tell the function to not change the link's color when it's underlined and you decide to hover over it.