# Making links active dynamically upon click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's default [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). I want the active page to be represented by a dark gray block dynamically upon clicking the link. I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the [code](http://www.codeply.com/go/QEMOrAtWcV) I have so far. It's similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098462/making-links-active-in-javascript) except I'm trying to integrate it with Bootstrap.

Codeply went down?
New demo with edits [here](http://www.bootply.com/tNDHIDRVsU).

Comment: Have you tried adding style to the `active` class like so: `.active {background-color: #333333 /*or some other color*/}`

Comment: Your demo doesn't show a working navbar (and you have a syntax error in your jQuery function, as indicated by the 'x').

Comment: fixing it now. thanks. 1st time codeply user.--getting "application error"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
$(".navbar-nav a").click(function() {
    $(".navbar-nav > .active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You and the OP are both missing closing parentheses on your functions.

Comment: Can't forget about those semicolons.

Comment: no @user1807271 - you want to listen to the .click event for all of the menu items right. So when a menu item is clicked then remove the active class from the active menu item and then add it to the one that was clicked.. :)